# Riggning issue: The arms of my character do not move properly

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I have a problem with rigging with a model of a nazi soldier.

I set the weights properly.

[image]

If I drag the bone up, the problems begin to happen, it's like some red zones aren't calculated by Blender, and so it doesn't look realistic.

[image]

Can you help me by telling how to properly set the weight?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your problem could be other bones are also influencing that part of the arm. Check the weighting on the surrounding bones, then on the rest of the bones in your armature.